# How to center modal window for ShareThis?

Tags: javascript, sharethis

I have implemented ShareThis, but the modal window opens next to the mouse click: http://jsfiddle.net/5XFgn/

How do I make the modal window open in the center of the page and also dim the background like in their demo here? http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475003-widget-positioning

I tried using the offset, but didn't work and the ShareThis docs are horrible and incomplete! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<span class="st_sharethis" st_url="http://sharethis.com" st_title="Sharing Rocks!"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://wd.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    stLight.options({
        publisher:'12345',
                offsetTop:'150'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Their example seems to contradict their documentation. I suggest you dig into their code and reverse engineer this.

Comment: Thx I tried doing this but the source code to that page is a mess. Probably because there are several demos and actual sharing implementations on the page.